# Is anything truly stochastic?

Tags: thermodynamics, probability, stochastic-processes

If everything in the universe happens according to rules, thermodynamic or otherwise, then how would anything (or any choice) ever be stochastic?

Multiple choices might be probable, but in any instant the ones that get chosen are based off of those rules. Doesn't that rule out stochasticity?

Comment: That is a nice discussion, but I'm not sure we took any stance there. Maybe this question truly is open-ended as of our current understanding. Anyway, I think the question I asked could be considered a duplicate.

Comment: I have never understood this kind of question in the context of *physics*, how would you test it experimentally that something is "truly" stochastic?